# Change/Overwrite thread ID of a thread

Tags: c++

I know it is possible to get the id of a thread by using GetCurrentThreadId(), however, is it possible to actually set the thread id? If so, how?

Ex: I want to change the thread ID of a thread from 5432 to 1234.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? A PID is an value used by the operating system, you shouldn't attempt to change it.

Comment: Why change the ID and not the string you use to compare threads? No one forces you to specifically compare the IDs.

Answer (score 0):

The ThreadID is assigned by Windows from internal tables.  You cannot change it.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683183%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> Until the thread terminates, the thread identifier uniquely identifies the thread throughout the system.

If thread ID modification would be possible, then you should disable creating new threads until you ensure that your ID is not used by anyone else. You will admit that is not realistic.